# Conditional mean independence- can it be a constant

Tags: endogeneity

Consider the linear regression model: $$y_{i}=x_{i}'\beta+\epsilon_{i}$$
  where the notation is conventional. For OLS to be unbiased, we need the conditional exogeneity assumption, or the fact that $\text{E} [\epsilon \mid x]=0$

I understand if the conditional mean of the error term is a function of x
  then we run into endogeneity problems. However, what if it is a constant? For instance, what if it is

$$
\text{E} [\epsilon \mid x] = c .
$$

I don't see a problem with this because the error term is not systematically varying with $x$,
 but is fixed. Therefore, when we use variation in $x$
  to compute parameter estimates, this should get 'differenced' away. Is this correct?

Comment: Perhaps, but it's not very useful to think this way.  We are free to *define* errors as deviations from means and if $\text{E}(\epsilon) \neq 0$ then $\epsilon$ isn't really an error term anymore because its mean becomes absorbed into $y$.  If we introduce an extra mean parameter then technically our model is no longer identifiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! This is perfectly fine, in fact this is one major reason why we always include a constant. It turns out that if $E(\varepsilon|x) = E(\varepsilon) \neq 0$ the value gets absored into the constant. To see this suppose that $E(\varepsilon) = c$, add and subtract $c$ from both sides of the 
\begin{align*}
y_i &= \beta_0 + x_i \beta_1 + \varepsilon_i + c - c \\
 &=(\beta_0 + c) + x_i \beta_1 + (\varepsilon_i - c) \\
&=\beta_0^* + x_i \beta_1 + \varepsilon_i^*
\end{align*}
So now $E(\varepsilon^*|x) = 0$ and OLS estimators $\hat \beta_0^*$ and $\hat \beta_1$ are unbiased for $\beta_0^*$ and $\beta_1$.